# python requests.get etree return empty

Tags: python, python-requests

I was trying to extract the movie information on IMDb with requests and etree.
I checked the response.status_code. it returned 200.
But when I copyed the xpath from Chrome Driver. nothing was returned. 
Could anybody help me check what's wrong?

```
base_url = 'https://www.imdb.com/'
movie = 'Ralph Breaks the Internet'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
response = requests.get(base_url,movie,headers=headers)
response.status_code

##returns:200

selector = etree.HTML(response.content)
selector.text

##returns:'\n    '##
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears several issue in your code. First i think you should know what url are you requesting.

```
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/'
movie = 'Ralph Breaks the Internet'
response = requests.get(url,movie,headers=headers)
print(response.url)
# https://www.imdb.com/?Ralph%20Breaks%20the%20Internet
```

Through your code variable `moive` and your description. I guess the url you desire is `https://www.imdb.com/find?ref=nv_sr_fn&q=Ralph+Breaks+the+Internet&s=all`.

Your selector did not select anything.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

base_url = 'https://www.imdb.com/find'

headers = {'User-Agent': 
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36',
                }

movie = 'Ralph Breaks the Internet'
params = {
    "ref" : "nv_sr_fn",
    "q" : movie,
    "s" : "all"
}

response = requests.get(base_url,params=params,headers=headers)
print(response.url)

selector = etree.HTML(response.content)


td_a = selector.xpath("//td[@class='result_text']/a")
print(len(td_a))
for ele in td_a:
    print("Moive:{} Year:{} Link:{}".format(ele.text,ele.tail,ele.get("href")))
```

Output:

```
https://www.imdb.com/find?ref=nv_sr_fn&q=Ralph+Breaks+the+Internet&s=all
10
Moive:Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018)  Link:/title/tt5848272/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1
Moive:Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9319312/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2
Moive:Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9167490/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3
Moive:Ralph Breaks The Internet: Into The Internet With Ralph and Vanellope Year: (2018) (Short)  Link:/title/tt9274902/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4
Moive:Ralph Breaks The Internet: NCM Piece Year: (2018) (Short)  Link:/title/tt9274886/?ref_=fn_al_tt_5
Moive:Ralph Breaks The Internet: Slaughter Race Year: (2018) (Short)  Link:/title/tt9274952/?ref_=fn_al_tt_6
Moive:Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9335792/?ref_=fn_al_tt_7
Moive:Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9335920/?ref_=fn_al_tt_8
Moive:Review de "Ralph Breaks the Internet" Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9239874/?ref_=fn_al_tt_9
Moive:The Girl in the Spider's Web/Ralph Breaks the Internet Year: (2018) (TV Episode)  Link:/title/tt9324796/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  etree.parse instead of etree.HTML:

```
from lxml import etree
response = requests.get(base_url,movie,headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    selector = etree.parse(response.content)
    print(selector.text)
```